# Why is my text not vertically in the middle on my CSS nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying and trying and no success :C
I've tried vertical-align:middle; but that doesn't work

I basically want the nav bar text to be in the center of the "nav" class div
It currently stays at the bottom and not sure why

Thanks in advance

Screenshot here:

[image: screenshot]

CSS

```
.nav
{
    padding:0;

}
.nav ul li
{
display:inline;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size:19px;
}
.nav ul li a:link
{
border-left:1px solid;
padding-top:18px;
padding-right:1%;
padding-left:1%;
background-image:url('/img/grad.png');
background-color:#f7f7f7;
color:#454443;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="nav">
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" style="text-decoration:underline; color:#003B57;">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about/index.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="articles/index.html">Articles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="devotions/index.html">Devotions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="biblestudy/index.html">Bible Study</a></li>
                    <li><a href="schedule/index.html">Schedule</a></li>
                    <li><a href="store/index.html">Merchandise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactus/index.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="donations/index.html" style="border-right:1px solid">Donations</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: You can have the same without using **image**. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/wc5guubp/11/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've `padding-top : 18px` in your `.nav ul li a:link` that will pad the `a` `18px` from `top` and not `bottom`.

You can use `padding-bottom:18px` too or you can set `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to 9px:

```
.nav ul li a:link{
    padding: 9px 1%;
    /* Other properties */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkhhLhv5)

Comment: zomg, thank you so much. I don't know how I didn't get it to work before. but now i got a slightly bigger problem. I'll update my question

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed `padding-top:18px;` and seen the behavior?

Try

```
padding-top:9px;
padding-bottom:9px;
```

Comment: Yes i've removed the padding. that's not it. I have that so the user can click the empty space above

Comment: I believe the 18px is causing it to stick to the bottom. Try this        padding-top:9px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;

Comment: This should definitely be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Agree, The One. I have modified to put the answer after the discussion.